# How to Create a form partial in rails to delete and update records with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to use a form inside a partial file to update and delete records but I am not sure about the routes(paths) to be used on the form. I have provided the form partial without the paths and with some information about my app. I need to help to fill the form with the correct routes

#### Task controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to project_path(@project)}
      format.js
    end

  end
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to project_path(@project)}
      format.js
   end
  end
```

#### _task.html.erb

```
<%= form_for '', remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
  <%= link_to "Remove", '', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

#### Task form

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @project, @project.tasks.build ],id:"new-task-form") do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :name%>
<%= form.submit %> 
<%end%>
```

#### Routes

```
resources :projects do
     resources :tasks
 end
```

Comment: What's the difference between `Task form` and `_task.html.erb` if both of them are about task?

Comment: hi @AntonTkachov i am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?autoplay=true) on railscast  .Really i don't understand the difference between the  two forms. What i want is adding a checkbox on the `_task.html.erb`for the task.completed attribute

Comment: I don't see any reference to `_task.html.erb` in this episode. Please provide exact minute/seconds where Ryan mentioned it or at least copy the code here where you render your partial. You have partial, but I have no idea how and where you render it